# "git diff-index --name-only HEAD" reports files under windows, but not under cygwin

Tags: git

Under cygwin with git version "git version 2.8.3", the command

```
git diff-index --name-only HEAD
```

reports no files.

Under windows with git version "git version 2.18.0.windows.1" I get a lot of old files that have found its way into .gitignore.

I tried to get rid of those files and did the following:

```
1. git rm -r --cached .
2. git add -A
3. commit
```

But that was not successful.

Comment: Because of two different Git  configurations run below command and compare the configuration settings 

git config --system --list
git config --global --list

Comment: I'm a bit confused here: you mean that you have one particular PC, and on that PC you have one Git repository, and in CMD you `cd \path\to\repo` and then run Windows Git 2.18.0.windows.1 `git diff-index --name-only HEAD` and get the long list of files; but then, on the *same* PC, you fire up a cygwin shell, `cd /path/to/repo`, and run Git 2.8.3 `git diff-index --name-only HEAD` and get no files?

Comment: @torek - yes exactly thats my case and my confusion.

Comment: That's very odd. This diff-index will compare HEAD vs the work-tree; perhaps the two versions of Git are getting different Git configurations (especially `--global` / home directory setting) and thereby a different global-ignore file (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore` and/or `core.excludesFile`).

Answer (score 0):

`git clean -dfxn` will show all files ignored in `.gitignore`. `git clean -dfx` will remove all files listed in the dry-run